# How to get modal popup to show image clicked on in a gallery?

Tags: javascript, php, html, modal-dialog

I'm creating a photography portfolio with an image gallery with images added on via an upload feature from/to a mySQL database. I'm trying to add a feature where when you click on a photo it opens in a modal popup so you can view the full image. However I am unable to get the modal to open the specific image that was clicked on and instead am getting the newest image in the gallery.

The php/html

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM gallery ORDER BY idGallery DESC;";
$stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
if(!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
  echo "SQL statement failed";
} else {
  mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
  $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);

  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo '       
     <a href="#" class="myBtn">
     <div class="myImg" style="background-image: 
       url(img/gallery/'.$row["imgFullNameGallery"].');"></div>

      </a>

    <!-- The Modal -->
    <div id="myModal" class="modal">

      <!-- Modal content -->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <span class="close">&times;</span>
        <img src="img/gallery/'.$row["imgFullNameGallery"].'" >
      </div>

    </div>
   ';
```

The JS:

```
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

var btn = document.getElementsByClassName("myBtn");

var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];


btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
}



for (var i = 0; i < btn.length; i++) {
  var img = btn[i];

  img.onclick = function(evt) {
    modal.style.display = "block";

  }
}

//close modal
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

I think the problem may be the image src line in the modal content

```
 <img src="img/gallery/'.$row["imgFullNameGallery"].'" >
```

Which is just adding the first image onto each modal rather than the target image. Is there a way I can change the modal content so it links to the target image that is being clicked on?

Comment: Open up your browser developer console. And check what kind of errors you're getting. First thing I've noticed that your Modal ID is not unique. Element IDs should be unique within the entire document.

Comment: Edit: The modalImg.src line shouldn't be there. It was something I tried before but it didn't work.

Comment: I've changed 'myModal' to a class rather than an ID, but this has stopped the modal working. Is this what you meant to do? Sorry I am new at web development. I'm not getting any errors in the developer console.

Comment: Personally, I would only have one modal element, not one per image.  Then, on click, set the image of the modal to the image of the clicked image.  Similar to what I think you were trying to do with that `modalImg` bit that you removed.  Having just one modal will make this easier.

Comment: @PatrickQ, This is exactly what I've done down below. In general Ellec approach is not good.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a parameter to the server telling it which image you want. You've never done this, you're just selecting all the image file names from the database in a select * query. The result is many modal elements all with the same id, so the JavaScript probably is just picking the first one it finds.

You need to append the sql query with a parameter passed from the page. The easiest way to do this is to do some sort of form submission where the user picks the image they want. The form submission reloads the page, but now supplying the parameter that php/sql needs to get back the right data.

Start by creating an image select form. For now its a text input, a better way might be to poppulate a select drop down.

```
<form action="relative/path/to/the/php/page">
    Image filename:<br>
    <input type="text" name="imageSelection"><br>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Use the the php parameters  to build a query. The name of the parameter is the name you gave the html element in the form. Consider switching to a **[prepared statement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) for security**.

```
if ($_GET['imageSelection']) {
$imageSelection = $_GET['imageSelection']
$sql = "SELECT * FROM gallery WHERE imgFullNameGallery = '$imageSelection' ORDER BY idGallery DESC;";
$stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
if(!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
  echo "SQL statement failed";
} else {
  mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
  $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);

  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo '       
     <a href="#" class="myBtn">
     <div class="myImg" style="background-image: 
       url(img/gallery/'.$row["imgFullNameGallery"].');"></div>

      </a>

    <!-- The Modal -->
    <div id="myModal" class="modal">

      <!-- Modal content -->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <span class="close">&times;</span>
        <img src="img/gallery/'.$row["imgFullNameGallery"].'" >
      </div>

    </div>
   ';
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this, mate!

http://jsfiddle.net/bn4t81ac/15/

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(e) {
  $('button').on('click', function(e) {
    $img = $(this).attr("data-src");
    $('#myModal img').attr('src', $img);
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" id="mymodal" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" data-src="http://blog.visual.ly/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/IMG_6424-1300x866.jpg">
  First IMG
</button>

<button type="button" id="mymodal" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" data-src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/07/16/13/17/kiss-3541905__340.jpg">
  Second IMG
</button>

<button type="button" id="mymodal" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" data-src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/08/06/16/30/mushroom-3587888__340.jpg">
  Third IMG
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div style="width:100px" class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <img style="width:100%" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/08/06/16/30/mushroom-3587888__340.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```